# Sentencias preparadas: consecuencias de la ausencia de free_result() o close()

Tags: mysqli

En el tema de sentencias preparadas que problemas generaría la ausencia de las dos siguientes funciones:

`close()` y `free_result()`

Probe los dos siguientes casos y no paso nada negativo:

**Cerrar la sentencia**: `$statement->close();` Estuve probando y si se usan varias sentencias sin usar `close();` por *encima* parece que no da error.

**Liberar resultados**, luego de un `while` o `for`: Utilizando while y for para generar listas de datos, llenar checkbox y demas e evitado colocar la funcion free_result() y no eh visto problemas.

Sin embargo realizo mi pregunta:
Ocurre algun problema si no uso `close()` y `free_result()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te diré lo que dice el Manual de PHP en ambos casos. Las negritas son mías, y son intencionales :)

### close ()

> Las conexiones de MySQL no persistentes y los conjuntos de resultados
>   son automáticamente destruidos cuando un script de PHP finaliza su
>   ejecución. Por tanto, **aunque el cierre explícito de conexiones
>   abiertas y la liberación de conjuntos de resultados sean opcionales,
>   se recomienda hacerlos. Así, se devolverán inmediatamente los recursos
>   a PHP y a MySQL, lo que puede mejorar el rendimiento.** Para
>   información detalla, véase la [liberación de recursos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct).

### free_result()

> **Siempre se debe liberar el resultado con `mysqli_free_result()`, cuando el objeto del resultado ya no es necesario.**

### Conclusión

¿`close()`? - > **siempre**

¿`free_result()`? - > **siempre**

¿Y si no quiero hacerlo?, quizá no pase nada **aparentemente**, pero tu programa no estará optimizado desde el punto de vista del rendimiento y podrías tener en algún momento errores del tipo `MEMORY EXHAUST` u otro. Entonces, en el caso de MySQLi, mejor cierra lo que abres... PDO es otra historia.

---

Enlaces:

- [`close()` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php)
- [`free_result()` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.free.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Las conexiones de MySQL no persistentes y los conjuntos de resultados
>   son automáticamente destruidos cuando un script de PHP finaliza su
>   ejecución. Por tanto, aunque el cierre explícito de conexiones
>   abiertas y la liberación de conjuntos de resultados sean opcionales,
>   se recomienda hacerlos. Así, se devolverán inmediatamente los recursos
>   a PHP y a MySQL, lo que puede mejorar el rendimiento.

[mysqli_close();](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.close.php)

> Siempre se debe liberar el resultado con mysqli_free_result(), cuando
>   el objeto del resultado ya no es necesario.

[mysqli_free_result();](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.free.php)

La realidad es que como lo indica la documentación de PHP, es opcional, no pasa nada, pero créeme que cuando las consultas ya son a nivel de producción y no de pruebas locales, la vida de la memoria del servidor es vital para la compañía.

Que te sirva, saludos.