# ¿Cómo imprimir esta consulta?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo estas dos consultas, os copio y pego directamente la parte pertinente del código:

(El valor de la variable $search_filter y $search_server lo recibo de un `$_POST`.)

1) Aquí básicamente quiero buscar todas las entradas de la tabla:

```
if ($search_filter == "mostrar todo") {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM Cuentas");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

2) Aquí quiero buscar todas las entradas que cumplan cierta condición:

```
if ($search_filter == "server") {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM Cuentas WHERE Server = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $search_server);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Preguntas:

A)¿Hay riesgo de inyección en alguna de las consultas?

B)¿Cómo puedo imprimir los resultados de ambas consultas de forma ordenada (lo más parecido posible a una tabla o texto con tabulado)?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Veo que estás empezando con MySQLi. Me permito sugerirte que en vez de MySQLi uses **PDO**. En estos dos enlaces (aunque en inglés) se explican varios motivos contundentes por los que es mejor usar PDO. Enlace 1: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison Enlace 2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11048666/5587982 Entre otras cosas, porque sólo hacer lo que planteas en tu pregunta requiere varias líneas de código, mientras que en PDO, lo harías en una sola línea. Más aún si tienes una clase de conexión configurada según tus necesidades. Aquí un ejemplo: https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respondiendo a: (A)**

En la primera consulta no hay riesgo alguno de inyección SQL porque en dicha consulta no entran los datos que recibes *desde fuera* a través de `_$POST`, por tanto no puede haber inyección.

En la segunda consulta no puede haber inyección SQL que podríamos llamar *de primer grado*. Pues la inyección SQL es un tema complejo. Para profundizar en el tema puedes ver [esta pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967). En mi respuesta a esa pregunta se desmontan algunos mitos sobre la protección contra la inyección SQL, entre ellos el uso de funciones obsoletas o creer que simplemente *escapando* caracteres ya estamos protegidos. La **mejor protección** contra la Inyección SQL es el uso de consultas preparadas, pero hay que tener en cuenta otras medidas de seguridad a la hora de establecer nuestra conexión a la base de datos. En algunos casos, si la conexión no se establece con los buenos parámetros, las consultas preparadas no funcionan y nos pueden colar una inyección. Pero ese es otro tema abordado en el enlace indicado más arriba.

**Respondiendo a: (B)**

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que funciona. El código está comentado con algunas explicaciones.

```
/*
    * Obtenemos una instancia de conexión llamando a la función conectar (). 
    * Lo ideal es tener una clase que maneje nuestra conexión. 
    * Luego verificamos si ha sido exitosa y procedemos
    * Si ha sido fallida imprimimos un mensaje indicándolo
*/  

$db=conectar();
if ($db)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM padres WHERE id_padre >= ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);     
    $id=1;
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

/*
    * Creamos una variable $html que iremos concatenando 
    * con las filas y celdas de la tabla
    * e imprimiremos al final
*/  


    $html="<table>";                
    $html.="<thead><tr><th>ENCABEZADO 1</th><th>ENCABEZADO 2</th></tr></thead>";
    $html.="<tbody>";

/*
    * Es realmente complicado obtener limpiamente un arreglo asociativo 
    * de nuestro resultado usando MySQLi, que nos obliga a asignar una variable
    * para cada valor esperado. Imaginemos una consulta con decenas o cientos de columnas
    * Es más facil con PDO, que trae ya métodos para obtener los resultados en arreglos
    * Pero... vamos entonces a implementar nuestra propia función: mi_fetchassoc
    * Cabe decir que MySQL tiene métodos parecidos, 
    * pero se necesita tener instalado el driver mysqlInd
    * 
*/  

    while($data = mi_fetchassoc($stmt))
    { 
/*
    * Dentro del bucle, concatenamos cada valor en filas y celdas de la tabla
    * usando las etiquetas <tr> y <td>
    * Habrá un <td> por cada columna que querramos presentar en la tabla
    * Sustituye $data["...."] en cada td por los nombres de columna de tu tabla
*/  
        $html.="<tr>";
        $html.="<td>".$data["padre"]."</td>";
        $html.="<td>".$data["id_padre"]."</td>";
        $html.="</tr>";
    }

/*
    * Fuera del bucle, completamos nuestra variable $html 
    * Luego la imprimimos
*/  

    $html.="</tbody></table>";
    echo $html;

/*
    * Liberamos los recursos 
    * El $stmt también hay que liberarlo
    * Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/61035/29967
*/  
    $stmt->free();
    $db->close();

} else {
    echo "no hay conexión";
}

/*
    * Una función personalizada
    * para obtener un arreglo asociativo del resultado
*/  

function mi_fetchassoc($stmt)
{
    if($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        $rs = array();
        $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$rs[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
        if($stmt->fetch())
            return $rs;
    }

    return null;
}

/*
    * Una función de conexión. 
    * Si tienes tu propia clase de conexión mejor
    * pues puedes usarla desde cualquier parte usando New
    * además, al conectar hay varias cosas a tomar en cuenta
    * como establecer en charset adecuado
    * manejar adecuadamente los posibles errores, etc
    * Poner en las variables los valores reales de tu conexión
*/  

function conectar () {
    $host="localhost";
    $usuario="tu_usuario";
    $clave="tu_clave";
    $dbnombre="tu_bd";
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$usuario,$clave,$dbnombre);

/*
    * Si no se pudo conectar retorna NULL
    * Si se conecta establece el charset y devuelve el objeto conexión
*/  
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    return NULL;
}else
/* cambiar el conjunto de caracteres a utf8 */
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    return $mysqli;


}
```

---

**Mi recomendación: Usar PDO en vez de MySQLi**

Por varios motivos se recomienda usar PDO en lugar de MySQLi, ya que PDO permite hacer con más facilidad cosas que en MySQLi resultan más complicadas. [En este enlace](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison), aunque está en inglés, se explican varios motivos por los que es mejor usar PDO.

Yo mismo he empezado a desarrollar [una clase que maneja mi conexión con PDO](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) y, una vez creada la conexión, con una sola línea de código podemos enviar la consulta preparada y obtener los datos en una variable.

Por ejemplo:

```
$datos=$mipdo->query(
                   "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id_provincia = :idprovincia AND id_estado = :idestado",
                   array("id_provincia"=>"1","id_estado"=>"5")
                  );
```

Luego se lee el valor de la variable `$datos` en un bucle... y listo.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que estés pasando los datos por **$_post**, puedes tener ataques de **xss**. Aquí te dejo una forma de tratar de evitar ese tipo de ataque. Esto incluso esto lo puedes hacer siempre que hagas envío de datos del formulario:

> Solo a $_post

```
$search_server = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre_del_campo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

Para mostrar el contenido a espacio iguales sin necesidad de usar una tabla y te quede tabulado lo puedes hacer con el método de php **str_pad()** [Ayuda php strp_pad](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php) te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$dato1 = "Hola";
$dato2 = "Mundo"; 
$data .= str_pad($dato1,20).str_pad($dato2,18).chr(13).chr(10);
```

> Nota: la longitud a rellenar, esta de acuerdo a la necesidad que se
>   requiera.