# ¿Por que un ciclo while no muestra datos existentes al utilizarse en PHP 5.3.0?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un ciclo while para mostrar una lista de datos usando el siguiente codigo:

```
 <?php
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT desc_unix ,cos_unix FROM unidadesx");
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultados = $stmt->get_result();
    $contador = 0;

    while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc())
      {
      $contador = $contador + 1;
      echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="112">' . $contador . '</td>';
      echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="192">' . $datos["cos_unix"] . '</td>';
      echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="596">' . $datos["desc_unix"] . '</td>';
      echo "</tr>";
      }

    $stmt->close();
    ?>
```

**Este funciona bien en PHP 5.4.0. Al pasarlo a PHP 5.3.0 no muestra nada.**

- Lo primero que hice fue testear el valor de `$resultados`, ya que hasta donde estaba esta sentencia se mostraba el HTML, tuve que cambiar de `get_result();` a `store_result();` para que mostrara todo el ocumento.
- Lo segundo fue que generaba las columnas pero no los datos crei que el problema estaba en el `fetch_assoc()` y lo cambie por `mysql_fetch_array`.
- Ahora muestra todo el contenido HTML pero no los datos, es decir, sale columna 1, 2 ,3 pero vacias.

Aqui el codigo final:

```
<?php
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT desc_unix ,cos_unix FROM unidadesx");
$stmt->execute();
$resultados = $stmt->store_result();
$contador = 0;

while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados,MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
  $contador = $contador + 1;
  echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="112">' . $contador . '</td>';
  echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="192">' . $datos["cos_unix"]. '</td>';
  echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="596">' . $datos["desc_unix"]. '</td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }

$stmt->close();
?>
```

**Como puedo hacer que este ciclo funcione en PHP 5.3?**

Comment: Víctor creo que estás creyendo usar mysqli (lo digo por la etiqueta que has puesto a la pregunta) pero **en realidad estás usando una función obsoleta de PHP que es `mysql_*`**. Dicha función fue declarada obsoleta porque **no es segura para manipular nuestros datos**. Se recomienda usar [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Yo particularmente prefiero PDO.

Comment: Victor, al pasar un codigo de una version de php mas reciente a una mas antigua, no te funcionara porque hay metodos que el antiguo no tiene y por eso te da fallos y por cierto te recomiendo que uses `mysqli` ya que `mysql` fue descontinuado

Comment: @A.Cedano lo siento, copie el que no era xD

Comment: [Este ejemplo puede servirte](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63033/29967)  para hacer lo que quieres de una forma clara y organizada, puedes adaptar las partes que varían, como los border color, los width, etc. Como verás, se usa MySQLi y se almacena el resultado en un arreglo asociativo. Todo lo que es HTML se almacena en una variable y se imprime al final. A mi me gusta trabajar así, pues demasiados `echo...` no me gusta.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por que no utilizar como en la documentación señala :

```
$sql = "SELECT desc_unix ,cos_unix FROM unidadesx";
$contador = 0;
foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $row) {
    $contador = $contador + 1;
    echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="112">' . $contador . '</td>';
    echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="192">' . $row["cos_unix"]. '</td>';
    echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="596">' . $row["desc_unix"]. '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: me da error 500, hay algo mal escrito

Comment: prueba ahora por favor @Victor-Random

Comment: Ups toda la razon! @MarcosGallardo  gracias!

Comment: **mysqli::query** realiza la consulta, pero no devuelve un array de resultado devuelve un objeto. Debe de utilizarse alguna de las funciones para tal fin.