# eficiencia al mostrar datos con PHP

Tags: php

A raíz de hacer una página web me ha surgido una duda. Al momento de mostrar por pantalla algún tipo de información mediante `echo`con php como sería mejor mostrar estos datos, en términos de eficiencia?

1. Mostrando todo con un solo `echo`:

   ```
   echo '<table><tbody><tr><th></th></tr></tbody></table>';
   ```
2. Mostrando todo con varios `echo`:

   ```
   echo '<table>';
   echo '<tbody>';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th>';
   echo '</th>';
   echo '</tr>';
   echo '</tbody>';
   echo '</table>';
   ```

Comment: Para mejorar la eficiencia, no te recomiendo que no ejecutes el código html con php. Ya que te ocupa mayor cantidad de memoria. Lo puedes hacer es intercalarlo. Si vas ha colocar una tabla como el ejemplo, no la imprimas con echo sino colócala como html y dentro de ella imprime el contenido de tus consultas con echo

Comment: En situaciones en las que hay que ir mezclando HTML/PHP yo prefiero crear una variable PHP e ir concatenando en ella los valores e imprimir al final. Un ejemplo típico es llenar una tabla usando un conjunto de resultados de la base de datos. Para mi gusto el código queda más limpio de esa forma. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63033/29967) hay un ejemplo de lo que digo.

Comment: Personalmente recomendaria utilizar motores de plantillas como twig. El tema de ir intercalando variables, o poner uno o varios echo complica luego la modificación de la app si solo tienes que cambiar el html, aparte que da esa mala "fama" al php de desordenado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviamente lo ideal es hacer un solo echo.

Se obtiene **mejor rendimiento utilizando comillas simples** que comillas dobles, ya que en las dobles el interprete de php primero mira si tiene que sustituir alguna variable que haya dentro de las comillas dobles.

Utilizar variables para almacenar y hacer un sólo echo posteriormente es más lento que hacer varios echos sin utilizar variables.

De todas formas piensa que estamos hablando de micro-segundos. Por lo que tampoco hay que complicarse mucho en ese aspecto.

Puedes ver en [phpbench.com](http://phpbench.com) comparativas de tiempos de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Actualmente la diferencia de comillas simples y dobles es insignificante. En versiones mas viejas de PHP esto si que podía llegar a notar.

Comment: Si te fijas digo que hablamos de diferencias de microsegundos.