# ¿Cuál es el uso correcto de las funciones y variables globales?

Tags: php, funciones, variables-globales

Recientemente he visto en la pregunta [¿Cómo crear una function global que contenga el id de la urls?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97539/c%C3%B3mo-crear-una-function-global-que-contenga-el-id-de-la-urls) que en una de sus respuestas se menciona que las ***variables globales son en general una mala práctica.***

> Como referencia existe esta pregunta:
>   [¿Por qué es considerado una mala práctica utilizar variables globales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29177/por-qu%C3%A9-es-considerado-una-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica-utilizar-variables-globales) existe una gran documentación confusa, cierta parte mal criticada las funciones globales, al menos que este confundido sobre el tema y que mis variables globales no sean globales.

Se dice en unas de las respuestas que las variables globales crean dependencias ocultas, cuando se trata de aplicaciones grandes mencionando que ni uno mismo sabe/recuerda/no se tiene claro los objetos que tienes y sus relaciones.

Las **variables globales** dentro de funciones son una gran utilidad, yo las considero de tal manera, a la hora de trabajar conjuntamente con `PHP` & `HTML`.

> En este ejemplo no veo como puede ser una mala práctica, al menos que exista alguna vulnerabilidad de seguridad en ellas.

```
$connect = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');

function user(){...
  global $connect; //conexión a la base de datos  

   // Código de la consulta
}
```

Resultado de la function en **HTML**

```
<div><?php  user();?></div>
```

**¿Me podrían explicar cómo sería una mala practica?**

**¿A qué variables se les determina como una variable global?**

Las palabras reservadas de **PHP** `global $conexion;` intervienen en el tema.

> **Nota:** Existe una pregunta de por qué es considerado una mala práctica, quizás este enlazado al mismo tema, pero la pregunta es muy distinta entre sí, existe la manera de uso pero no ejemplos para novatos en programación, mucha teoría sin práctica sería confuso, en resumen la respuesta se trata de ver más el lado malo a una solución, es para mí  algo muy confuso entre tantas lineas a pesar que tengo experiencia programando.

Comment: Es más cómodo usar variables globales ya que no hay que definirlas en cada procesos/función, además de que si están globales, el valor que tiene cargado no se pierde, a diferencia de que si están definidas localmente.

Comment: Tienes que aclarar tu pregunta si es funciones globales o variables globales y puede confundir.

Comment: @Einer He publicado un ejemplo de código, no veo donde no este claro, se ha tenido muy buenas respuestas hasta se le ha iniciado una recompensa por otro usuario SO.

Comment: @Einer Creo que si han comprendido el ejemplo está desde el inicio de la pregunta

Comment: No, no fue asi. Publique una respuesta orientada a las funciones globables, no variables globales y recibio mala puntuacion. En un lugar escribes: "Las funciones globales son de mucha utilidad". Mientras que en otro: "Se dice que las variables globables crean depedencias..". Es muy confuso porque escribes sobre algo que no tiene que ver con el tema y ademas lo resaltas tambien la descripcion de la apregunta. Lo que lo hace doblemente confuso responder bien. Y en cima de todo, muestras una pregunta de SO que tiene que ver con funciones globales.

Comment: En una pregunta sobre como crear una `function` global @A.Cedano menciono que es una mala practica crear variables globales. Menciono los dos temas en sí entonces debe ser familiarizado las funciones globales con variables globales.

Comment: @Einer Sobre todo en mi pregunta no solo se basa a las funciones globales, también he mencionado las variables globales sobre todo una pregunta ¿A qué variables se les determina como una variable global? creo que deberías leer detalladamente mi pregunta y las dependencias de ellas es decir los enlaces de referencias.

Comment: Si las globales en general son una mala práctica, en PHP son ¡un peligro!.  Te dejo solamente [esta referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/5587982), en ella hay otras respuestas que podrían sacarte de dudas. En cuanto al ejemplo de la conexión, ¿cómo haces si necesitas conectarte a la bd desde 100, 200 o 500 partes distintas en una aplicación? Si creas 500 líneas como estas en cada parte: `$connect = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_contraseña', 'sakila');` ok, ok, pero ¿qué pasará cuando se cambie la contraseña? ¿Te **acordarás** de los 500 sitios donde te conectas a la bd?

Comment: [En este caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102112/29967) hay un ejemplo típico del problema del uso de globales (leer comentarios). Sin duda el OP tardó uno o varios días tratando de encontrar el problema en su código, aseguraba que la conexión funcionaba y resulta que el problema era estar usando la conexión en una variable `global`. ¿Quizá la variable fue seteada a `null` en alguna parte y no se sabe dónde? Él estaba seguro de que su variable `global $con` funcionaba, pero resulta que no funcionaba, pues como todo el mundo puede usarla, quizá alguien la anuló en alguna parte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yendo al grano y hablando desde un punto de vista estrictamente de `PHP`

### ¿Por qué evitar las variables globales en PHP?

1. Las variables globales **son más costosas que las locales**. Ya que obliga a PHP a escanear todo el ambito de variables hasta encontrarla, por lo que una variable local dentro de una función siempre será más rápida que una global.
2. **Reducen la reusabilidad del código**. La razón es que todos los proyectos no tienen las mismas variables globales por lo que una función que utilice variables globales dificulta la reutilización de dicha función. en POO directamente rompen la encapsulación.
3. Las **funciones que utilizan variables globales pueden llevar a engaño**, esto esta ligado al punto anterior. Una funcion que el argumento este pasado en el cuerpo como global puede aparentar que no necesita argumentos, lo que puede generar un código confuso y ambiguo. Si una función requiere argumentos mejor pasarlos directamente.
4. Al utilizar variables locales en lugar de globales existe menor probabilidad de conflicto de nombres con otras variables, ya que las variables locales solo existen en el ámbito local.
5. **Las variables globales pueden ser modificadas desde cualquier parte del programa**, algo que puede dar muchos dolores de cabeza ya que sera difícil saber donde y cuando se ha modificado.

Ejemplos al final.

---

### ¿A qué variables se les determina como una variable global?

Las variables globales **son aquellas variables que estan definidas en el ámbito general del programa** [(ámbito de las variables)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php). Por otro lado tenemos las [superglobales](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php) que además de lo anterior también pueden ser accedidas desde cualquier parte del programa directamente, `PHP` provee múltiples variables [superglobales](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php) entra ellas [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.globals.php) que es un segundo método para acceder a las variables del ámbito global.

---

### Funciones globales

Si nos referimos a **funciones globales**, en el manual podemos encontrar lo siguiente:

[Funciones definidas por el usuario](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.user-defined.php)

> **Todas las funciones** (no confundir con los métodos de una clase) **y clases de PHP tienen ámbito global**. Se pueden llamar desde fuera de una función incluso si fueron definidas dentro, y viceversa.

---

### Métodos de clase globales

Cómo tal no se pueden declarar los métodos de una clase como globales, por lo que no se pueden utilizar directamente en el ámbito global sin instanciar antes la clase, básicamente los métodos globales no existen. No obstante, `PHP` nos permite declarar [métodos estáticos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php), estos métodos estaticos podrán ser accedidos en cualquier ámbito, anteponiendo el nombre de la clase y el [doble dos puntos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) a dicho método estático (`miClase::miMetodo( )`).

---

### Ejemplos

Ejemplo punto 3

```
// Función con global
// Más lento/más costoso
// Argumento en cuerpo, resulta en una dependencia escondida
$var = 'miConexion';
function mi_funcion()
{ 
    // Depende de que $var exista globalmente 
    global $var;
    // Resto de operaciones
    // $var puede ser modificado globalmente 
}

// La llamada aparentemente no necesita argumentos
// pues aparentemente no se pasa nada a la función 
mi_funcion(); 

/*-----------------------------*/

// Función SIN global
// Más rápido/menos costoso
// Argumentos requeridos claros
function mi_funcion_2($conexion)
{ 
    // Operaciones con $conexion
    // $Conexion solo se puede modificar localmente 
}

// sabemos que se está pasando a la función
mi_funcion_2('miConexion');
```

Ejemplo punto 5:

```
<?php
// Modificar el valor de $var
$var = 'Hola';
function mi_funcion()
{
    global $var;
    $var.= ' mundo!';
    echo $var; // Hola mundo!
}

mi_funcion();
echo $var; // Hola mundo!

/*-----------------------------*/

// NO modifica el valor de $var
$var = 'Hola';
function mi_funcion_2($var)
{
    $var.= ' mundo!';
    echo $var; // Hola mundo!
}

mi_funcion_2($var);
echo $var; // Hola
```

El beneficio de utilizar variables globales en `PHP` es minimo y utilizarlas por comodidad no es más que vagueza.

Comment: un +1 has dado con algunos puntos importantes sobre este tema.

Comment: No entiendo. Tu pregunta fue acerca de las funciones globales, no variables globables.

Comment: @Xerif ahora no estoy de acuerdo que el uso de una variable `global` sea por vagueza. El asunto es que yo utilizo una variable global pero mi variable global es solo de la conexión a la base de datos, o es más factible crear una consulta por cada`function mifunction(){} `

Comment: @J.Doe ¿Y qué te impide pasar la conexión a la función como argumento en lugar de utilizar las globales? es decir `function mifunction($conexion){}`

Comment: Buena respuesta, es en gran parte lo que digo [en la respuesta referida por @J.Doe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/55926/29967) Para el caso específico de la conexión a la BD, ¿por qué mejor no tener una clase dedicada a ello y cuando necesitas la conexión creas un objeto conexión, que además podría tener métodos personalizados adaptados a tu aplicación? Tener una conexión _deambulando como global_ por la aplicación me parece una muy mala idea, a no ser que tu aplicación sea un plugin.

Comment: @A.Cedano Que gran orientación. Pero vamos a un problema que tratan de evitar usando las variables globales que se trata el inconveniente de los cambios que puede presentar al realizar algún cambio de la variable, si están conciente que al crear las funciones de la siguiente manera `function mifunction($conexion){}` al realizar el cambio por ejemplo de la variable que tiene la conexión deben cambiar la variable de la `function` y donde se esta imprimiendo los resultados de la `function` en otra página por ejemplo que se este imprimiendo `<?php echo mifunction($conexion); '>`

Comment: @A.Cedano Es una gran orientación toda la documentación a la que se han dedicado a discutir es una gran ayuda sabre todo estas contra, solo quedaría una duda por plantear una nueva pregunta, en cada `function` si es necesario incluir el cierre de la consulta de la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: @J.Doe eso depende. Si usas PDO no es necesario cerrar nada, puedes ver al respecto [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967), documentada, de una pregunta de esas que yo llamo _abandonadas_. Si usas MySQLi, puedes [ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/61035/29967), relativa no a la conexión en sí, si no a otros objetos que se crean a partir de ella. En cualquiera de los dos casos, lo mejor es tener tu propia clase que gestione todo, incluida la posiblidad de evaluar si hay algún objeto conexión antes de crearlo...

Answer (score 3):

Cuando se plantea como diseñar un sistema de información, la forma de hacerlo para que resulte mantenible en el tiempo, y por diferentes personas,  es dividirlo en sub-sistemas mas simples tendiendo a llegar unidades lógicas (programas) que tengan una única responsabilidad, que se comporten como si fueran un “componente”. Y por otro lado reducir al mínimo las dependencias entre estos programas.

En la medida en que mejor podamos cumplir con estos dos objetivos más rápido un nuevo programador puede entender el funcionamiento del sistema, y menos complejo es cambiar, reemplazar, o eliminar alguno de los programas.

Las variables principalmente caen del lado del las dependencias.

Una variable local a una función, nace y muere dentro de la función y ningún otro programa sabe de su existencia. Entonces, si la función es modificada y esa variable cambia de nombre, de tipo de dato, de rango de valores, o se elimina,  el impacto del cambio queda dentro de la función y mientras que esta función siga recibiendo los mismos datos como parámetro y siga entregando el mismo resultado, al resto del sistema le es transparente lo que se haya hecho con esa variable local.

Ahora, supongamos que esta función utiliza una variable global, esto es una variable que está definida a nivel del sistema y todos los programas, funciones, procedimientos tiene acceso a ella la usen (lean y/o modifiquen) o no. Eso significa que ya no es sólo la función la que puede leer o modificar esa variable.
La variable global crea una dependencia entre la función y el resto de las funciones, programas, o procedimientos que también utilizan la misma variable global, y esto hace más complejo el mantenimiento. Es decir, si tenemos que eliminar esa función, cambiarle el tipo de dato a la variable, o su rango de valores, hay que revisar en todos lados donde se utilice esa variable para determinar el impacto del cambio, y en muchos casos este tipo de dependencias provoca que una modificación en una función, traiga aparejado más modificaciones en otras partes del sistema que a simple vista parecen no tener relación.

Cuando esto se piensa en sistemas con cientos de programas y miles de líneas de código, y se le suma la rotación de programadores, lo más probable es que alguno de estos cambios no sea detectado y aflore en producción de forma totalmente inesperada e incluso en apariencia no relacionada con la modificación que se hizo, lo que contribuye a que sean errores también muy engorrosos de corregir.

**EDICIÓN I**

Respecto a mantener la conexión a la base de datos en una variable global.

Si se usa una sola conexión que no se cierre hasta que no termina el programa, la variable ya es global por naturaleza ya sea que la guarde en una variable global o se la pase como parámetro por todo el sistema, y no está exenta de los problemas mencionados. Por ejemplo, al hacer un mantenimiento, alguien puede introducir inadvertidamente el cierre de la conexión en algún lado, o hacer un commit o un rollback de una transacción en un lugar incorrecto y afectar otras funciones que se hacen más adelante en el flujo del programa (para dar un par de ejemplos).

La otra opción es abrir una conexión cada vez que se necesita hacer un query y cerrarla después de haberlo ejecutado.

Pero abrir conexiones a la base de datos es costoso en términos de tiempo. Entonces se suelen balancean los pros y contras de ambas opciones y si los pros superan a las contras se opta por dejar la conexión como recurso global y se toman algunas otras medidas como para mitigar la ocurrencia de problemas.

Un ejemplo es reduciendo al mínimo las funciones que usan la conexión. Sería el caso de tener una única función o una familia de funciones bien conocidas que reciba/n los parámetros del query, lo ejecuten y devuelve el resultado a la función invocante vs. que cada función use la variable global directamente.

En esto de balancear los pros y contras hay varias cosas para considerar para ir por uno u otro camino.  Entre ellas: detalles de implementación del driver de la base de datos, si se usan pools de conexiones, y si el sistema se ejecuta en un solo hilo o si admite concurrencia.

En el caso de PHP entiendo que corre en un solo hilo y lo más conveniente es abrir la conexión y mantenerla abierta. Por lo que mantener una conexión global es una alternativa viable y se pueden mitigar los riesgos reduciendo el número de funciones que utilizan la conexión.

Comment: El asunto es que yo utilizo una variable global pero mi variable global es solo de la conexión a la base de datos, o es más factible crear una consulta por cada `function mifunction(){}`.

Comment: es un gran ejemplo ahora entiendo en que sentido puede afectar al cambiar el nombre de x variable global, tocaría cambiar a todos los documentos que contenga esta variable x global, **Hasta aquí he comprendido** pero explícame el asunto de la conexión a la base de datos es más factible entonces crear una consulta por cada `function`

Comment: aunque pensando sobre la problemática sobre la variable global ahora en la actualidad existen editores que dan la posibilidad de cambiar o reemplazar una variable con un cierto nombre y reemplazarla por otro nombre y este realiza el cambio automáticamente en todo el documento se cambia el nombre de x variable al nuevo nombre de la variable que se le asigne.

Comment: Agregué el tema de la conexión a la base de datos a la respuesta. Respecto de los editores que permiten buscar y reemplazar los nombres de variables, ayudan mucho cuando el problema ya lo tenés. Pero no sería mejor evitar el problema directamente?

Answer (score 1):

Al ser un tema subjetivo como una mala práctica, pueden existir distintas opiniones.
Generalmente cuando empezás a programar (sin importar el lenguaje) se cae en la tentación de incluir todo el código dentro de una única función (main) porque simplemente parezca mas práctico (al comienzo).

Cuando el desarrollo es chico, y administrado por uno mismo, puede que sea mas práctico usar variables globales en algunas situaciones.
Pero cuando el desarrollo es grande, y hay bastantes archivos a veces se pierde el seguimiento o trazabilidad de las variables mas cuando son globales.

Usar variables globales además rompe un poco la modularidad del desarrollo, es como usar el GOTO en C.

Es una buena práctica usar el menor número de variables globales posibles, pero en la mayoría de casos, si las usas simplemente no va a pasar nada.

Comment: El asunto es que yo utilizo una variable global pero mi variable global es solo de la conexión a la base de datos, o es más factible crear una consulta por cada `function mifunction(){}`.

Comment: Siempre es mejor abrir y cerrar la conexión a la base de datos cuando sea necesario.
Aunque en frameworks como CodeIgniter, CakePHP, donde el sistema es muy grande y por cada acción se consulta con la base de datos, no se si los frameworks mantienen abierta siempre la conexión globalmente o internamente la cierran y abren solo cuando sea necesaria.

Comment: su comentario es muy bueno para realizar un nuevo tema, aunque quizás al final de la `function` se puede añadir el cierre de la consulta, creo que funcionaria. ¿Me quedo la duda?

Comment: Para dudas tan puntuales, que van mas enfocadas al rendimiento, se debería probar a fondo (mas que nada en un desarrollo grande) ambas formas (o las opciones que haya) y constatar en cuanto a (tiempo, procesamiento, espacio) cual es la mas óptima.
Aunque tampoco vendría mal, saber cual es la opción mas correcta.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me pasaba lo mismo, queria hacer uso de mis variables de conexion, datos de usuario, ... en cualquier punto pero me resultaba frustrante la mala legibilidad del codigo, estuve estudiando el uso que hacia PHP de las variables y funciones y al final llegue a una conclusion (mas o menos acertada, pero que funciona), paso a contarosla.

PHP se podria decir que funciona en circulos de actividad, donde uno seria el hilo principal del programa, y todas las variables y funciones declaradas en el, y otro el que comprende a los objetos (clases).
Todas las variables y funciones del hilo principal son globales y pueden ser llamadas directamente (funciones) o mediante la declaracion "global" (variables).
Las clases se adhieren al hilo principal al instanciarlas o invocarlas (clases static), ademas pueden ser englobadas en otros circulos de actuacion mediante la creacion de "namespaces", unen al hilo principal sus funciones declaradas "public" (por defecto si no declara otra cosa) y mantienen como propias las "private".

Mas o menos (a grandes rasgos) como funciona la parte global y privada de PHP.
Ahora bien, el problema que nos ocupa es hacer mas legible el codigo y no perder la parte global de las variables esto se puede conseguir con las funciones de clases "static", una funcion static no necesita tener su objeto asociado instanciado para poder ser llamada (al igual que una variable static), solo necesita tener el objeto cargado bien con "include" o "require".

```
    <?php class MyConfig{ 
             public static $user='Javier';
             public $amigo='Pepito'; 
             public static function abreviatura(){
                 return substr(self::$user,0,3);
             }
          }
          function getAbreviaturaDeJavier(){
                 return MyConfig::abreviatura();
          }
          echo 'Mi nombre es '.MyConfig::$user.' y abreviatura '.getAbreviaturaDeJavier();
?>
```

Aqui podemos ver como usar esos objetos estaticos, la clase MyConfig tiene una variable estatica $user y una funcion estatica abreviatura(), estos son globales si la clase esta cargada y llamables desde cualquier punto del programa, lo malo de las funciones y metodos estaticos es que son eso "estaticos" no admiten el llamar a metodos del objeto sin instanciarlo, por ejemplo:

```
  function abreviatura(){
       return substr($this->amigo,0,3);
   }
```

Esto nos daria un error, ya que, el metodo static no tendria acceso a las variables (no static) del objeto MyConfig.
Pero una variable static es como una variable global, ejemplo:

```
class MyConfig{
  public static $clientIp='10.10.10.10';
}
function getRealIP(){
  MyConfig::$clientIp=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
echo getRealIP();
echo MyConfig::$clientIp;
```

En el ejemplo anterior el objeto MyConfig declara y asigna un valor a la variable $clientIp, que luego es modificado por la funcion getRealIP(), en los dos echo posteriores el valor devuelto es el mismo, ya que, la funcion modifica el valor de la variable del metodo.

Si todo esto lo aplicamos al problema de la conexion a la bbdd nos quedaria:

```
class DB{
    public static $conexion;
    public static function conectarDB($user,$pass,$server){
        self::$conexion=new DB($user,$pass,$server);
        }
   function __construct($user,$pass,$server){
        return new PDO->connect($user,$pass,$server);
   }
}

DB::conectarDB('miuser','mipass','miserver');

function getUser($id){
   $query=DB::$conexion->query('select * from user where id='.$id);
   return $query->fetch();
}

$user=getUser(2);
```

Las bases de datos y el conector PDO tienen suficientes funciones como para que no nos haga falta mantener mas de una conexion abierta a la bbdd (fetch_all) y de esta forma dispondremos de metodos y variables globales para usar donde nos plazca.

Ademas de esta forma el codigo es mucho mas legible, ordenado y ampliable.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya han explicado el uso de variables globales rompería de alguna manera encapsulamiento. 
Cuando pensamos en objetos los mismos tienen que tener una alta cohesión y bajo acoplamiento para que puedas reutilizar el código.
Pero cuando hablas de un sistema no todo puede convertirse en un objeto que represente el "ámbito del dominio" del problema, también tienes que dar solución al "ámbito de la solución", valga la redundancia, por lo cual esta muy bien el uso de variables globales. Por esta razón la mayoría de los lenguajes orientados a objetos permiten el uso de de datos compartidos sin necesidad de crear objetos para ello. El error a mi entender es que utilices ese mecanismo en forma descontrolada y no estudiada.

Por ejemplo, quizás quieras tener dos variables globales SESSION['tmpNomUsu'] y SESSION['tmpIdUsu'] las cuales pueden ser accedidas desde cualquier parte del programa. para aumentar el control puedes encapsular dichas variables en una clase y acceder a estas siempre desde un objeto.

```
class tmpVal(){

    definirTmpNomUsu($tmpNomUsu){
       $_SESSION['tmpNomUsu'] = $tmpNomUsu;
    }

    obtenerTmpNomUsu(){
       return $_SESSION['tmpNomUsu'];
    }

    definirTmpIdUsu($tmpIdUsu){
       $_SESSION['tmpIdUsu'] = $tmpIdUsu;
    }

    obtenerTmpIdUsu(){
       return $_SESSION['tmpIdUsu'];
    }

}
```

Ahora sabes que tus variables globales están encapsuladas en una clase, podrías violar el "contrato" accediendo desde otro lugar que no sea la clase "tmpVal" de la misma forma que lo harías realizando llamadas a la DB desde fuera de una clase.
Por otro lado, aprovechas un mecanismo sencillo para resolver un problema sencillo sin necesidad de hacerlo complejo.

Comment: agrega un ejemplo de variables globales  y encapsulamiento para que tu respuesta sea valida

Answer (score 0):

Como habrás leído en las respuestas anteriores, generalmente se considera una mala práctica el uso de variables globales, no solo en PHP, sino en general, en casi cualquier lenguaje de programación.

Algunas razones para no utilizar variables globales...

- El código fuente es más fácil de leer y mantener, ya que tenemos una idea clara de dónde se están afectando los valores y tenemos menor
  incertidumbre de cambios no esperados.
- No hay validaciones de qué valores son permisibles y cuáles no. No
  tenemos la certeza de que en cualquier punto de la aplicación se esté
  modificando a un valor no esperado (si solo debemos aceptar enteros
  positivos, no hay garantía de que en algún lugar se asigne un valor
  negativo).
- Alto Acoplamiento. Un programa con uso de variables globales, se
  vuelve dependiente de esas variables y complica la modularización
  ¿Qué va a pasar si requiero llevar una parte/módulo del sistema y hay
  una dependencia de variables globales? Sin duda implicará un esfuerzo
  de adaptación.
- Problemas de concurrencia. Si se puede acceder a una variable desde
  múltiples hilos, se requiere asegurar que se controle el acceso
  concurrente en cada punto en que se pueda modificar.
- Conflictos de nombres. Las variables locales pueden tener el mismo
  nombre de una variable global, lo que implica que eventualmente se
  podría tener bugs generados porque estoy intentando modificar el
  valor de una variable distinta de la que se intenta.

Estos puntos los tomé como base de un artículo en el siguiente link: http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

En relación a las conexiones de Base de Datos, es cierto que son caras y resulta mejor no estar abriendo y cerrando; sin embargo, algunos gestores de base de datos (Oracle y SQL Server), implementan un pooling de conexiones, a través del cual se optimizan los procesos de apertura y cierre, básicamente reutilizándolas (una especie de cache de conexiones).