# No se pudo obtener mysqli Error PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

> estoy usando la funcion global $con; y el error se fue pero no se si
>   este bien que lo use en cada funcion y si en PHP5 funcione igual de
>   bien que en PHP7

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\trending.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\trending.php on line
>   21

codigo:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From trending, ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT 13");

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0)
    {
        for ($n=1;$n<=12;$n++){
            echo'<div class="div_css_one">';
            echo'#</div>';
            echo'<div class="div_css_one_b">';
            echo'</div>';
        }
    }else{  

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<li><a href="hashtag?hashtag='.$data['hashtag'].'"><p class="font-weight">#'.$data['hashtag'].'</p></a><spam class="trending_post_top">'.$data['top'].' posts</spam><li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: @abrahamhs ESE ES MI ERROR

Comment: Error de sintaxis aquí: `Select * From trending, ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT 13`

Comment: Siempre es bueno en el código controlar todo lo que podría ser nulo o no funcionar. ¿Estás comprobando el estado de la conexión? Por ejemplo: `if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
}else{$sql = mysqli_query($con,"Select * From trending ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT 13");//Código de consulta y demás}`

Comment: la conexion esta bien porque tiene un if 500 por si la conexion esta mal me avisa es otra cosa pero no se a cual

Comment: Ese error indica casi siempre problemas con la conexión. ¿Puedes poner en la pregunta el código que hay antes? ¿No habrás cerrado `$con` o se llama de  otra manera o algo así? ¿Esa consulta te trae datos si la pruebas en el manejador de base de datos directamente?

Comment: El problema esta en tu variable $sql, ya que mysqli_num_rows() esta esperando un conjunto de valores, pero esta recibiendo NULL, entonces es $sql el error. Tienes que verificar que este bien la conexion y que este bien el nombre de la tabla que estas consultando.

Comment: @A.Cedano tu codigo me dice lo mismo `Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\demo.php on line 9` no hay error de conexion que pasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es necesario un control total del código para que puedas saber dónde está fallando:

```
//Controlar conexión
if (!$con) 
{ 
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL.";

}else{

    //Controlar consulta
    if (mysqli_query($con,"Select * From trending ORDER BY top DESC LIMIT 13")=== TRUE) 
    {

        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0)
        {
           for ($n=1;$n<=12;$n++)
           {
              echo'<div class="div_css_one">';
              echo'#</div>';
              echo'<div class="div_css_one_b">';
              echo'</div>';
            }
          }else{  

          while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
          {
             echo '<li><a href="hashtag?hashtag='.$data['hashtag'].'"><p class="font-weight">#'.$data['hashtag'].'</p></a><spam class="trending_post_top">'.$data['top'].' posts</spam><li>';
           }
           //Cerrar recursos usados si fuere necesario
    }else{
           echo "Consulta errónea, revise la instrucción SQL: ".$sql
    }
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RQLY6eg.png hablamos por un chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65538/algo-interesante

Comment: @Shareiv el mensaje de la imagen indica que hay un error en la consulta. O la tabla `trending` no existe, o no tiene una columna llamada `top`.

Comment: estoy usando la funcion ´global $con;´ y el error se fue pero no se si este bien que lo use en cada funcion y si en PHP5 funcione igual de bien que en PHP7

Comment: El uso de globales no es una práctica recomendada, precisamente por lo que te está ocurriendo entre otras cosas: es difícil controlar y depurar cuando ocurren errores y fácilmente pierdes horas/días tratando de encontrar dónde está el problema. Quizá la conexión fue destruida en alguna parte del código y cuando la intentas usar tienes el error. Sugiero que empieces a usar el estilo orientado a objetos, que crees una clase que maneje la conexión y cuando la vayas a usar crees tu objeto conexión con `new`. Así tendrás control de tus objetos siempre y sabrás lo que pasa en cada instante.

Comment: mira te voy enviar un file para veas como tengo las funciones y para que me digas si esta mal hecho ok

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzcdeIOejP5xU21aaXA4NTJNcDQ

Answer (score 1):

Tu query esta incorrecto, tiene una `,` de más, al finalizar la lista de campos. Esto provoca que la función regrese un *FALSE*.
Ese *FALSE* es lo que le pasas a la función `mysqli_num_rows`, que es lo que te genera el segundo warning.

Puedes ver más detalles de [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) Y [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)