# Tengo un problema con variables globlales en PHP

Tags: php, variables-globales

Tengo una función definida que funciona perfectamente.

```
<?php 

    $GLOBALS['vphplon'] = $_REQUEST['lon_pt']; 
    $GLOBALS['vphplat'] = $_REQUEST['lat_pt']; 

    echo "coordenadas" ;

    echo "$vphplon";
    echo "$vphplat";
?>
```

Pero cuando accedo desde otra función en otra página php me dice que las variables son inexistentes.

```
protected function doBeforeInsertRecord($page, &$rowData, $tableName, &$cancel, &$message, &$messageDisplayTime)
        {

            echo '$vphplon';
            echo '$vphplat';

            $rowData['vlon'] = '$vphplon';
            $rowData['vlat'] = '$vphplat';


        }
```

Alguien ve donde puede estar el error ?

Comment: y si haces un `include` del archivo donde estas definiendo estas variables en tu otro archivo donde las requieres?

Comment: Estas haciendo una mala interpretación de los ámbitos,  que una variable pertenezca al ámbito global no significa que pueda ser utilizada en cualquier lugar, te animo a que revises estas preguntas: [¿Cuál es el ámbito y el ciclo de vida «real» de una variable global en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/118598/38103) y [¿Cuál es el uso correcto de las funciones y variables globales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100319/38103)

Comment: Totalmente cierto, hice un incluye. Y todo funciona perfectamente.  Muchísimas gracias:)